# HTML Table with cell background text

Tags: html, calendar, html-table

What is the best way to go about displaying an html table with text in the background of each cell? I am making a calendar and I would like to have grey dates in the background of actual text.

The only thing I can think of at this point is to have the date and the cell content in separate divs that float over one another but even that isn't implementing well within a table.

By the way using an image to display the date is not really an option IMHO.

Comment: If the background has text you probably don't want any foreground text to obscure the background text, correct?

Comment: No, the background text is just a date and it will be a slightly different colour and dramatically larger so it will still be decipherable and could be deduced by the fact that the table is a calendar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use relative positioning in the content span:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <span class="day">6</span>
        <span class="contents">Contents go here</span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

And in CSS:

```
span.day {
    line-height: 20px; /* just to give it a height */
    display: block;
    color: #aaa;
}

span.contents {
    position: relative;
    top: -20px;
}
```

Now the spans are overlapping, with contents over day number. You might want to adjust the position but this should work.

Even though this would work, I would advise you to use images. You can embed all the required dates in one image file (the CSS sprite technique), it gives you greater control with less browser specific issues.

Comment: what happens if the content spans 2 lines?

Comment: Ah I was mixing them up, i see what you did now.

Comment: Ah muck, this is what I had been trying and it wasn't working because of jquery... argh (btw prepend and append don't work on the contents of table data)

Comment: The only problem is that it leaves a lot of bottom padding

Comment: Add negative `margin-bottom` to compensate.

Comment: Okay, I was just about to comment - the way I solved it was to change top to margin-top (also just make it negative)

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... if I understood correctly, the way I would do it is probably something like the following in each cell:

```
<div class="cell_container" style="position:relative;">
    <div class="cell_bg" style="position:absolute; width:100%; 
        height:100%; z-index:0; color: gray;">29/12/2009</div>
    <div class="cell_fg" style="position:absolute; width:100%; 
        height:100%; z-index:1;">Jim's birthday</div>
</div>
```

Naturally, you can move the styles into a seperate css file.  You might also be able to do away with the container div and just apply the "position:relative;" style to the containing cell.  The major downside to this method is that you will lose the ability to vertically align in IE, without some trickily implemented workaround.

Comment: Nice, the date is not a full date just the day of the month - I'll give that a bash - looks good

Comment: Yeah i thought so, but I wasn't sure so I just stuck today's date in :)

Comment: I am using an actual table, so with this the div goes flying out wherever it feels like going... (because of position:relative) - it just generally ignores the table structure.

Comment: Have you tried applying position:relative to the <td> element?

Comment: Ja, without the div - it still disrespects the table structure. With the container div, it at least stays within the bounds of the table but the rows are messed up.

Answer (score 0):

I realize you said that using an image is "not an option IMHO", but may I suggest that using images would give you a lot more flexibility in the appearance of the date. You could use any font available to your image editor, rather than the limited set of fonts you can count on in a browser. And all sorts of image tweaking tricks could be aplied that would be immpossible in the browser.